# Does Visual Studio 2010 provide any enhancement or additional features to a server with and existing installation of Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, SSDT, installed in addition to SQL server 2012 provides a Visual Studio shell.  I'm curious if installing a full version of Visual Studio 2010 provides any enhancement or additional features.

Comment: u are curious of any initial thing or some breaking changes?

Comment: Not exactly.  Just curious about features that may not be available if VS is not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on what version of VS you're installing. If you're installing Premium or Ultimate you will get collaboration tool benefits. Other than that, not much.

Comment: Any known matrix comparison available of features added by VS aside from collaboration tools?